# Choosing alternating numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

There are 3000 cards, each labeled with an integer, 1 to 3000.
Alex chooses 2000 different cards. Bob then tries
to find from these 2000 cards, 1000 cards whose odd or evenness alternates when they are placed in increasing order. If Bob is able to complete his objective, he wins, otherwise, Alex wins.
Who is assured of winning, given they play wisely?

Answer (score 2):

Bob.
Group the numbers like $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\cdots$
Alex chooses $2000$ different cards, i.e. he abandoned $1000$ of them.
For each group, if one card is abandoned, Bob should abandon the other too.
At last Bob abandon some 'whole group's arbitrarily.
$500$ groups are remained and Bob's objective is completed.

Comment: How can you prove 500 groups remain?

Comment: For each group it is either both elements remained or both abandoned according to my strategy. There are 1000 numbers left, so 500 groups remain. Note that in the final part of the strategy Bob needs to remove some 'whole group's if too many numbers are left.